# Splitting run-time and configuration mode in core-nlp

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am using stanford's core-nlp pipeline to perform some basic tasks. Below is a sample code copies from the tutorial.

```
public static void testcoreNLP(String inputText) throws IOException {

  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
  props.put("coref.md.type", "rule");
  props.put("coref.mode", "statistical");
  props.put("coref.doClustering", "true");
  props.put("ner.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz,edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz,edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz");
  StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

  StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
  Annotation document = new Annotation(inputText);

  pipeline.annotate(document);
  List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

  for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
        for (CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
          String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);
          String pos = token.get(PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
          String ne = token.get(NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);      
      System.out.println("word: " + word + " pos: " + pos + " ne:" + ne);
    }  
}
```

My method `testcoreNLP` (accepting String inputText) is being called by another method (textPreprocessor() which pre-process the text) within its `for-loop`.

As I understand, everytime a to `testcoreNLP` method, loads all the model files (certain domain specific -trained model file) which consumes around 3-5 secs per run.

How do I split the model loading from runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Your Java application only needs to build the pipeline once.  You can take the pipeline loading code out of the method and just execute that once.